# Derive a recurrence relation for the number of ways of obtaining n cents of postage if the order matters.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Full question: "Suppose that we have 10 cent stamps, 18 cent stamps, and 28 cent stamps, each in unlimited supply. Let f(n) be the number of ways of obtaining n cents of postage if the order in which we put on stamps counts. If n > 29, derive a recurrence for f(n). Find f(66)."

Textbook answer: f(n) = f(n - 10) + f(n - 18) + f(n - 28), f(66) = 13

I am trying to understand how they got f(n)... when I see the answer, it does not look clear to me. It must be something to do with the order.

Additionally, how to find f(66) in the most efficient way possible? It takes me forever trying case after case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make $n$ cents, you can start with a way to make $n-10$ cents and add a $10$ cent stamp, or ...  That is the logic behind the recurrence.  To compute it in a spreadsheet is easy.  Make a column for $f(n)$.  The base cases are $f(10)=1,f(18)=1,f(20)=1, f(28)=3, f(n)=0$ for $n \lt 28$ except $10,18,20$.  Then in line $29$ put =up10 + up 18 + up 28 and copy down.  I find $f(66)=25$  There are $10$ with $3\cdot 10+2 \cdot 18$, $12$ with $2 \cdot 10+1\cdot 18+1\cdot 28$ and $3$ with $1\cdot 10+2\cdot 28$.  I think the author missed the middle case.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the orderings of stamps that add up to $n$ cents. Then there are $f(n-10)$ orderings such that the last stamp in the ordering is a $10$ cent stamp, $f(n-18)$ orderings such that the last stamp in the ordering is a $18$ cent stamp, $f(n-28)$ orderings such that the last stamp in the ordering is a $28$ cent stamp, and these are all possible orderings. Hence the recurrence relation.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now!